# OSX - Error: Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=4.0.1 is required

Tags: mono, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Omnisharp isn't starting on my OSX 10.11.2 (El Capitan) Visual Studio Code (0.10.3).  It worked some versions back, but an update broke the functionality and hasn't worked since.

I've followed the error link, but `brew update/reinstall/uninstall/install mono` doesn't seem to affect the error in the editor.  My current version of mono (as installed by `brew`):

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d Wed Dec  2 14:02:18 PST 2015)
```

Is there something I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start VS Code app from the command line.

```
$ open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an environment thing. If an app is launched via the Terminal, the Terminal passes in its environment settings to the app. I'm looking into getting this to work without the Terminal.